# Change cursor on widget mouseover (PyGObject)

Tags: cursor, gtk, pygtk

I've been trying to change the cursor on Gtk.ScrolledWindow() (it has an image widget in it) mouseover:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

  def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Test")

    self.maximize()

    grid = Gtk.Grid()
    self.add(grid)

    scrolled = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scrolled.set_hexpand(True)
    scrolled.set_vexpand(True)
    scrolled.connect("motion-notify-event", self.mousemove)
    grid.add(scrolled)

    pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file("anyimage.jpg")
    image = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
    scrolled.add(image)

  def mousemove(self, widget, event):
    print("Mouseover triggered")
    circle = Gdk.Cursor(Gdk.CursorType.CIRCLE)
    widget.get_window().set_cursor(circle)

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
```

The event is triggered but instead of a circle the cursor is displayed as an arrow with a "disabled" symbol as its subscript.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Then it might be a bug with PyGObject (I'm on Arch Linux with PyGObject 3.32). Other cursors (like Gdk.CursorType.CROSS) work as expected.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have read your question a bit closer. It does NOT work for me, I get the same 'not available' symbol tacked onto my default cursor. I then tried some of the other ones, like Gdk.CursorType.CLOCK, and they work.

Comment: No problem, it's a minor issue but I'll report it to the issue tracker nonetheless. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wrong, it's not a bug. It's entirely up to the cursor theme in use. I was recommended to stick to cursors listed by name here:

https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.24/gdk3-Cursors.html#gdk-cursor-new-from-name

Those correspond to CSS and are most likely to be available across cursor themes.